# How to save text of more than 1500 bytes on Google datastore with gcloud-node?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud-node

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses?hl=en I should use a Blob type but I don't see such type in gcloud-node. Is it something yet to be implemented? How can I save long text in datastore using gcloud-node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a property is not indexed, you can store up to 1 MB. ([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Properties_and_value_types))

See [this example](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.20.0/datastore/transaction?method=save) for how to disable indexing explicitly.

Have you tried saving data and received an error?

Comment: Yes, I am saving a json object with a property that contains text that is more than 1500 bytes, and I received a 400 response saying the property can't be more than 1500 bytes. I am using the standard method to save data in a dataset from gcloud-node.

Comment: Okay, let me know what happens if you mimick the example that turns off indexing.

Comment: I tried with this method it works, thank you very much! But it means that you need to save your object as an array of objects with one object per field, and the property 'excludeFromIndexes' set to true for the field that is more than 1500 bytes.

Comment: You should accept @Stephen 's answer because it works perfectly